# MySQL IN for strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array `$friends` and I used `$friend_new = join(',',$friends );` to get `name1,name2,name3`.
But when I use this query I got error:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect_db, "SELECT * FROM post WHERE name IN ($friend_new )");
```

Does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `implode("','", $friends)` and `IN ('$friends_new')` as these are string values.

---

Your code is vulnerable to injection.  You should use properly parameterized queries with PDO / mysqli

Comment: +1 for being the only one to mention SQL injection and suggest PDO.

Answer (score 3):

Your list has to look like:

```
... IN ('friend1','friend2','friend3')
```

If you have an array of friends such as:

```
$friends = array("friend1","friend2","friend3");
```

You can use `implode` to prepare for use with an `IN`:

```
$friend_new = "'" . implode("','", $friends) . "'";
```

Finally,

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE name IN ($friend_new)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it the individual strings won't be quoted, and that causes the error.  As join allows you to specify a "glue" longer than 1 character you can do as follows:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect_db, 
                      "SELECT * FROM post " . 
                      "WHERE name IN ('".join("', '", $friends)."') ";
```

or

```
$friend_new = join("', '", $friends);
$query = mysqli_query($connect_db, 
                      "SELECT * FROM post " . 
                      "WHERE name IN ('$friend_new') ";
```

that is, have join write the intermediate `', '` , and surround with `''`